# Run VBA against all rows with a specific value in cells in one column

Tags: vba, excel

First - I am not a VBA expert and can call myself an intermediate excel user. I have an extensive VBA macro that I am trying to apply to only about 55 rows out of several hundred.

I then want to run the same macro against another set of rows with a different value in the same column as previous.

I have tried to brute force it with separate macro's but have been unsuccessful. The code below works for all rows in the entire worksheet, but I want to run it against ie. Rows 2:54. And again against 55:107. And again...

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub ChkInvAvail()


'Color any cell GREEN when the number of parts on hand is equal or greater to the corresponding re-order value
'Color the cell RED when the number of parts on hand is less than the corresponding re-order value
'Color cell A1 Green if all inventory levels are satisfactory. Color A1 Red if not
Dim OnHandCol As Long
Dim ReOrdPntCol As Long
Dim OnHand, ReOrdPnt, rngOnHand, rngReOrdPnt, AllRedGreenCells, OxmoorGreenCell As Range
Dim ShoreViewGreenCell, SilasGreenCell, StLouisGreenCell, PhoenixGreenCell, WECGreenCell As Range
Dim LastRowA, LastRowB, lastRow, DataStartRow As Long
Dim r, i, j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

    '2 Lines Below Column Address Can Be Changed if Needed
    Set rngOnHand = ActiveSheet.Range("I:I")
    Set rngReOrdPnt = ActiveSheet.Range("M:M")
    '1 Line Below Single Cell Address in Col C Can Be Changed if Needed
    Set AllRedGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set OxmoorGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("E3")
    Set ShoreViewGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("E4")
    Set CharlotteGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("E5")
    Set StLouisGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("E6")
    Set PhoenixGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("E7")
    Set WECGreenCells = ActiveSheet.Range("E8")

    '1 Line Below Row the actual data starts changes
    DataStartRow = 2

    LastRowA = MaxRowInXlRange(ActiveSheet, rngOnHand.Address)
    LastRowB = MaxRowInXlRange(ActiveSheet, rngReOrdPnt.Address)
    lastRow = Application.Max(LastRowA, LastRowB)

    OnHandCol = rngOnHand.Column
    ReOrdPntCol = rngReOrdPnt.Column

    i = 0
    j = 0

    For r = DataStartRow To lastRow

        Set OnHand = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r, OnHandCol), Cells(r, OnHandCol))
        Set ReOrdPnt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r, ReOrdPntCol), Cells(r, ReOrdPntCol))

        If OnHand.Value >= ReOrdPnt.Value Then
            OnHand.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'RGB Code for GREEN
            'ReOrdPnt.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Remove Comment if you want B to Be GREEN too
        Else
            If OnHand.Value >= ReOrdPnt.Value * 0.5 And OnHand.Value > 0 Then
                ReOrdPnt.Interior.Color = RGB(240, 240, 50) 'RGB Code for Yellow
                'ReOrdPnt.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Remove Comment if you want B to Be GREEN too
                j = j + 1

            Else
                ReOrdPnt.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ''RGB Code for RED
                'OnHand.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Remove Comment if you want A to Be RED too
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If i > 0 Then
        AllRedGreenCells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        If j > 0 Then
            AllRedGreenCells.Interior.Color = RGB(240, 240, 50)
            Else
            AllRedGreenCells.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function MaxRowInXlRange(xlWsh As Excel.Worksheet, DataRange As String) As Long
Dim MaxRow As Long
Dim ColRow As Long

    'Begin Find Last Row
    MaxRow = 1
    ColRow = 1
    For Each col In xlWsh.Range(DataRange).Columns
        ColRow = xlWsh.Cells(xlWsh.Rows.Count, col.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If ColRow > MaxRow Then
            MaxRow = ColRow
        End If
    Next
    MaxRowInXlRange = MaxRow
    'End Find Last Row

End Function

Function MaxColInXlRange(xlWsh As Excel.Worksheet, DataRange As String) As Long
Dim MaxCol As Long
Dim ColRow As Long

    'Begin Find Last Row
    MaxCol = 0
    ColRow = 1
    For Each rw In xlWsh.Range(DataRange).Rows
        ColRow = xlWsh.Cells(rw.Row, xlWsh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ColRow > MaxCol Then
            MaxCol = ColRow
        End If
    Next
    MaxColInXlRange = MaxCol
    'End Find Last Row

End Function
```

Situation is I have 20 columns of data. I have location values in column B with comparative data in columns I and O. I already have the macro to do what I want against the entire worksheet, but want to break my results out based on the location value in column B.

I am sure there is an easy way to do this, but with my limited imagination, I can't seem to figure it out.

Thoughts?

Comment: try adding your code to the question that you are trying to do fix.

Comment: How does your macro currently work through all rows in the column? Without seeing your code, I'd consider just adding an IF statement, i.e. IF range("B1").value = "Location" Then ...

Comment: Can you show some codes?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a little trouble following what you are trying to accomplish but I am gathering you are trying to compare the values in one colum to thoes in another?

If so I would try something like

```
last1 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
last2 = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to last1        
    For j = 2 to last2
        'Check if val in 'B' matches val in 'I'
        If(Range("B" & i).value = Range("I" & j).value) then
            'If match then colour cell
            Range("I" & j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    next j
next i
```